# Sequelize grouping by date, disregarding hours/minutes/seconds

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Hey so im trying to query from a database, using Sequelize (Node.js ORM for postgreSQL), im trying to group by date range, and keep a count of how many items where in that table.

Right now the code i have is

```
 Task.findAll({
    attributes: ['createdAt'],
    group: 'createdAt'
  })
```

But as you can see the grouping only takes into account the exact date (including seconds) so the grouping is actually pointless since no matter what there will be no overlapping items with the exact same second count.
So i want it to just be group based on day, year and month.

Im assuming that it will have to be something like sequelize.fn(...)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As you said, it's done with `sequelize.fn(...)` and there is no other way. Try:

```
Task.findAll({
  group: [sequelize.fn('date_trunc', 'day', sequelize.col('createdAt'))]
})
```

I think that might do the job. If not, we'll see how to do it ;)

Notice that PostgreSQL allows you to truncate to specific intervals. For more information visit: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC

Also, to understand how group (and order) works see the documentation of Sequelize: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/172272c8be9a847b2d64f0158826738703befddf/docs/docs/models-usage.md#manipulating-the-dataset-with-limit-offset-order-and-group

Comment: @repo glad to help! You can also upvote the answer for future viewers. I'm going to include the documentation of sequelize for the group property

Comment: @barbarity how do you do when you want to truncate with a specific timezone?

Answer (score 13):

The selected answer didn't work here.

This is what is working for me.

```
Task.findAll({
    attributes: [
        [Sequelize.literal(`DATE("createdAt")`), 'date'],
        [Sequelize.literal(`COUNT(*)`), 'count']
    ],
    group: ['date'],
})
```

Comment: MariaDB wanted fieldname without quotes...
`
[Sequelize.literal(`DATE(createdAt)`), 'date']`

Comment: @AnttiA very well. My answer was tested on PostgreSQL.

Comment: MySql also needs fieldname without quotes, but otherwise it works

Comment: Error: FUNCTION cms.date_trunc does not exist

Answer (score 2):

**For Sequelize and MYSQL**

This what worked for Me:

```
Model.findAll({
      attributes: [
        /* add other attributes you may need from your table */
        [sequelize.fn('DATE', sequelize.col('createdAt')), 'Date']
      ],
      group: [sequelize.fn('DATE', sequelize.col('createdAt')), 'Date']
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

For Sequelize MySQL:
I wanted to `count` data `group by` `month` for given `year`,

This helped me:

```
Model.count({
      where: {
        createdAt: sequelize.where(
          sequelize.fn("YEAR", sequelize.col("createdAt")),
          "2022"
        ),
      },
      attributes: [
        [sequelize.fn("MONTH", sequelize.col("createdAt")), "month"],
      ],
      group: ["month"],
    })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "month": 8,
        "count": 2
    },
    {
        "month": 9,
        "count": 1
    }
]
```

Comment: This works for me, how can I have all months and count 0 if no data found.

Comment: @Donkagunila
Whatever month is not returned, the frontend (or whoever is calling the API) should consider that 0 as default value. Or, you might need to write custom logic after, `.then((result) => {`

Answer (score 0):

you can also try:

```
     group:'DATE(date_added)' 
     or
     group:'WEEK(date_added)'
     or
     group:'MONTH(date_added)'
```

though you will have to set you sql_mode = "" since you'll otherwise get the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY error.