# Sequelize Query Group by day objects found by parent property

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, group-by, sequelize.js

So, I'm using sequelize with a mysql instance and I have this hierarchy : a task has n images and also n metadata key value pairs. 
I want to get all images based on userId column of task, and afterwards get them grouped by 'createdAt' column taking into consideration the day, since a normal groupby will be pointless ( no objects share the same datetime ). I did lots of test to try to group, and I ended up using this query, which gives bad results ( I have like 11 images for a task, and it retrieves 4 ). Honestly, i don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any of you have any idea? 
This is the code snippet:

```
var userId = security.utils.getKeycloakSubject(req);
var where = {
    userId: userId
};
db.image.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: db.task,
        include: [{
            model: db.metadata,
            as: 'metadata'
        }],
        where: where
    }],
    group: [db.Sequelize.fn('DAY', db.Sequelize.col('image.createdAt'))]
}).then(function (images) {
    return res.json(images);
}, function (error) {
    return res.status(500).json(error);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw your question and also found this: [Sequelize grouping by date, disregarding hours/minutes/seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35073918/sequelize-grouping-by-date-disregarding-hours-minutes-seconds)
It is a question about group the **DAY(createdAt)**, looks similar with yours.

And my solution of GROUP BY DAY() is look like:

```
    item.findAll({
         attributes: 
       [[sequelize.fn('DATE_FORMAT', sequelize.col('TimeStamp'), '%H'), 'dates']],
         group: [sequelize.fn('DAY', sequelize.col('TimeStamp'))]
       }).
         then(function(result){console.log(result)
       }).
         catch(function(error){}).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
       });
```

So the raw SQL likes: `SELECT DATE_FORMAT('TimeStamp', '%H') as 'dates' FROM tableName GROUP BY DAY('TimeStamp');`

Hope it helps you, or you can show us the SQL you want to use, maybe it is easier to help you too.

Good luck.