# How to fetch sequelize js records for today

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have a table which looks similar to the below table. I am trying to find the sum of all prices for TODAY.

```
| id| price |       created        |
|---|-------|----------------------|
| 0 |  500  | 2018-04-02 11:40:48  |
| 1 | 2000  | 2018-04-02 11:40:48  |
| 2 | 4000  | 2018-07-02 11:40:48  |
```

The below code is what i came up with but it doesn't seem to work.

```
const TODAY = new Date();
const SUM = await OrdersModel.sum('price', {
    where: {
      created: TODAY,
    },
});
console.log(SUM);
```

Value of SUM is 0 even though there are entries for today. I also tried the following but it too didn't work.

```
const TODAY = new Date();
const SUM = await OrdersModel.sum('price', {
    where: {
      created: Sequelize.DATE(TODAY),
    },
});
console.log(SUM);
```

The SQL statement queried on the terminal is as follows.

> Executing (default): SELECT sum(`price`) AS `sum` FROM `orders` AS `orders` WHERE `orders`.`created` = '2019-05-27 18:30:00';

Comment: I updated the solution so you will not have problems, if you think that is the solution please mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem here is that you are comparing timestamps like `'2019-05-27 11:40:48'` and `'2019-05-27 18:30:00'`. So, if we compare them it will never give us a `true` result because even if it were the same day (27th of May) the time is different.

Here is a possible solution.

```js
const Op = Sequelize.Op;
const TODAY_START = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
const NOW = new Date();

const SUM = await OrdersModel.sum('price', {
    where: {
      created: { 
        [Op.gt]: TODAY_START,
        [Op.lt]: NOW
      },
    },
 });
 console.log(SUM);
```

You need to create a query like this: `created < [NOW] AND created > [TODAY_START]` **Why?** because you will get the sum of all the prices registered after `NOW`. This code will help you also to get the total of a range of dates.

#### Alternative for PostgreSQL

Notice that PostgreSQL allows you to truncate to specific intervals. So, you can call the `sequelize.fn()` method to use create a query that calls 'date_trunc' you can [read more in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35075239/5372008). Like this:

```js
const SUM = await OrdersModel.sum('price', {
    where: {
      sequelize.fn('CURRENT_DATE'): {
        [Op.eq]:  sequelize.fn('date_trunc', 'day', sequelize.col('created'))
      }
    },
});
console.log(SUM);
```

Also remember to update to the [latest version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize):

```bash
npm i sequelize@5.8.6 --s
```

Comment: Hi, I am still getting the SUM as 0  and there is no change in the executed SQL query on the terminal.

Comment: Hey try with less than to see what you get probably the error is in another part

Comment: Op.lt gives a value. How ever it gives the sum for all the previous dates right.

Comment: Then try this alternative, I think I know what is going on. Are you comparing  exact timestamps?? like `'2019-05-27 11:40:48'` equal to `'2019-05-27 18:30:00'` this comparison will never give you a result because it is the same day (27th of May) but the time is different.

Comment: Yeah so i tried using Op.gt and using Today date and changing the time to midnight. That works.

Comment: Check the explanation why do I use `gt` and `lt` and I fixed my mistake. I switch `gt` with `lt`. Now will be working fine.

Answer (score 5):

Best way to get **today records**.

```
      const op = sequelize.Op;
      const moment = require('moment');
      const TODAY_START = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD 00:00');
      const NOW = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD 23:59');

      const todaysRecord = await OrdersModel.findAll({

                where: {
                    createdAt: {
                        [op.between]: [
                            TODAY_START,
                            NOW,
                        ]
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

We can also use [op.between], which will fetch data between two given date Range. So if we give today's Start time and current time it will give todays data.

```
const Op = Sequelize.Op;
const START = new Date();
START.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
const NOW = new Date();

where: {
createdAt: {
    [Op.between]: [START.toISOString(), NOW.toISOString()]
  }
}
```

Happy Coding...

Answer (score 0):

Add DATE FUNCTION to do date comparision without considering time

```
const TODAY = new Date();
const SUM = await OrdersModel.sum('price', {
    where: {
      sequelize.fn('CURRENT_DATE'): {$eq:  sequelize.fn('date_trunc', 'day', sequelize.col('created'))}
    },
});
console.log(SUM);
```

Comment: Hi what do you mean by add DATE function ?

Comment: using DATE function you will compare with the date value and it will ignore the hh:mm:ss values

Comment: is it a custom function which i should write or part of sequelize ?

Comment: Ref to updated code in the comment sections, its a built in function sequelize.fn('date_trunc', 'day', sequelize.col('yourdatefiled')) . So it will consider only date part

Comment: You can't use a function an object key this will cause an error.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' sequelize.fn('CURRENT_DATE'): {

Comment: TODAY has not been used !

Answer (score 0):

Using moment would be easier

```
const moment = require('moment');
const Op = require('sequelize').Op;
const SUM = await OrdersModel.sum('price', {
    where : {
                created_at : { [Op.gt] : moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD 00:00')},
                created_at : { [Op.lte] : moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD 23:59')}
            },
});
console.log(SUM);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Sequelize.literal`:

```
    const { Op } = Sequelize;
    const options = {
        where: {}
    };

    options[Op.and] = [
        sequelize.where(Sequelize.literal('DATE(created) = CURDATE()'))            
    ] 

    const SUM = await OrdersModel.sum('price', options);
    console.log(SUM);
```

If there is no future date you can query like below,

```
    options[Op.and] = [
        sequelize.where(sequelize.col('created'), {
            [Op.gt]: Sequelize.literal('DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)')
        })            
    ]
    const SUM = await OrdersModel.sum('price', options);
    console.log(SUM);
```