# Count records for each day between the startdate and enddate in sequelize ORM (Performing this query in nodejs)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, datetime, count, sequelize.js

I am passing start_time and end_time as a query parameter in an API and want to have count of the records on each day from start_time and end_time.
It is giving me total count of records between the specified start and end_time but I want count for each day individually.
Example start_time: 2017-10-07 and end_time is 2017-10-10
So, I want count for the number of records on the date: 2017-10-07, 2017-10-08, 2017-10-09 and 2017-10-10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a `GROUP BY` clause in your sql to group your count by days. Here's documentation on how to do that with Sequelize.
https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#grouping

And if your date isn't just a single day, but has hours and minutes, you might need to do some `date truncation` in your `group by`. Here's some info on that:
[Sequelize grouping by date, disregarding hours/minutes/seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35073918/sequelize-grouping-by-date-disregarding-hours-minutes-seconds)

Comment: Thank you this worked. I used it already but I because my date wasn't a single day it was giving error.

Comment: One more follow up question, now i am able to count grouped on time but I want the count coming in order latest date count should come first and rest so on. Can this also be done as part of this?

Comment: Search the docs for "orderBy" or "order by"

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. I included sequelize.fn(date trunc, 'my parameter') with group by. But one more follow up query, in case for any particular date if the count comes up to 0 then group doesn't return anything but I want to return 0 instead of that. How can that be possible?